# how to add two arrays in Kotlin Data Structures

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I'm Kotlin beginner, i'm trying deceide leetcode exersizes, and I've got one question.

for example

```
val numbers = intArray(1, 2, 3)
val numbers2 = intArray(4, 5, 6)
```

make with help for loop,get

```
val number2 = intArray(5,7,9)
```

not this `val number2 = intArray(1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Comment: 4 people already have viewed my question, no one couldn't answer?? or you're not wish??

Comment: Nobody is obliged to answer any questions, let alone within 7 minutes of asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) to combine the two arrays to a `List<Pair<Int, Int>>`, and then [`map()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) to compute the sum:

```
fun main() {
    val numbers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    val numbers2 = intArrayOf(4, 5, 6)
    val sum = numbers.zip(numbers2).map { (a, b) -> a + b }
    println(sum.joinToString(", "))
}
```

Output:

```
5, 7, 9
```

---

The above is probably the most Kotlin way of doing it. But if you really want to produce an array and use loops, you can do it like this:

```
fun main() {
    val numbers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    val numbers2 = intArrayOf(4, 5, 6)
    val sum = IntArray(numbers.size)

    for (i in numbers.indices)
        sum[i] = numbers[i] + numbers2[i]

    println(sum.joinToString(", "))
}
```

Output:

```
5, 7, 9
```

---

However, you can produce the array directly without looping, by providing a lambda to the `IntArray` constructor:

```
fun main() {
    val numbers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    val numbers2 = intArrayOf(4, 5, 6)
    val sum = IntArray(numbers.size) { numbers[it] + numbers2[it] }
    println(sum.joinToString(", "))
}
```

Output:

```
5, 7, 9
```